# Using html and javascript to allow whether a form action gets called or not is not working (echoed in php)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, confirm

I initially had some code written in PHP / HTML that when a button was clicked, the form action took the user to the PHP page called delete.php.

Now i want to add a function in javascript that asks the user whether they are sure they want to go through with the action once they click the button, but I'm not sure how to not let the PHP form submit the form action if the user chooses to cancel.

This is the code:

```
    #delete buttons    previous code: <form action='delete.php' method='post'>
    echo "<form onsubmit='return setAction(this)' method='post'>";
    echo "<td> <button onclick='askConfirm()' type='submit' name='deleteItem' value='" . $line['productCode'] . "' />Delete</button></td>";
    echo "</form>";

    # end table row and loop
    echo "</tr>";
    
    # javascript
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">

    function setAction(){

      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?") == true) {
        form.action = "delete.php";

      } 
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    </script>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple. This `onsubmit` attribute will prevent form submission if the confirmation dialogue is cancelled.

```html
<form action="delete.php" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: would i delete setAction() then? Not super sure how to implement this within the code I have

Comment: Yes, you would not need it as it will not be called. The `onsubmit` in my solution takes care of the `confirm();` and form submission.

Comment: Thank you! So i deleted the things inside the script and now just have:             echo "<form action='delete.php' onsubmit='return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');' method='post'>";
            echo "<td> <button type='submit' name='deleteItem' value='" . $line['productCode'] . "' />Delete</button></td>";  but whenever i click a button it just directly deletes the record, instead of showing up as a confirmation box

Comment: The problem is from your quotes, specifically with the `onsubmit` attribute: `'return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');'`. The second quote is closing your quotation so that `Do you really want to submit the form?` is not quoted and anything following is not part of your attribute. I suggest using double quotes for HTML attributes. Where needed, you can use backslashes to escape quotes. This is how it would look: `echo '<form action="delete.php" onsubmit="return confirm(\'Do you really want to submit the form?\');" method="post">';`.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!!